# Why doesn't row-cols-n work for any value greater than 6?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

As far as I can see, the row-cols- classes don't work for anything greater than 6 ie row-cols-6 works but row-cols-7 has no effect.

This means that something like

```
<div class="row row-cols-md-6 row-cols-lg-8">
```

always shows 6 columns for anything greater than the md breakpoint because the row-cols-lg-8 class is ignored.

1. Is this right or am I doing something wrong?
2. If it is right is there a reason why it stops at 6?

Comment: Setting the `$grid-row-columns` SASS variable works as expected: https://codeply.com/p/29WHHch1fQ

Answer (score 0):

1. Your syntax is correct.
2. Bootstrap CSS (currently latest version 5.3.0) rules only go up to row-cols-6. I can only guess they don't deem it necessary to go higher than 6 cols per row.

To fix it I added a rule to my bootstrap.min.css file (needs a different approach when using CDN)

```
.row-cols-xl-7>*{flex:0 0 auto;width:14.28571429%}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was reported in [this Github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36691) and a "fix" was added in [this commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/e57a94cd664aa7b819da9408053bfbdf414a78e4), which closed the issue. However, the fix makes it possible to compile your own version of Bootstrap with a higher limit by setting the SASS variable `$grid-row-columns`; that variable still defaults to 6. In my view, that's a bug, and it should have all the steps up to 12, but I guess not doing that saves a few bytes.

If you don't want to compile a custom version of Bootstrap with changed SASS variables, you can add the missing styles manually into your custom CSS.

For example, for 7 columns the extra styles would look like this:

```
.row-cols-7 > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 14.2857143%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .row-cols-sm-7 > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 14.2857143%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-cols-md-7 > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 14.2857143%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row-cols-lg-7 > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 14.2857143%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row-cols-xl-7 > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 14.2857143%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .row-cols-xxl-7 > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 14.2857143%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put all your columns inside Rows like this and see how it works....

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
       <!-- Content for column 1 -->
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       <!-- Content for column 2 -->
   </div>
</div>
```

OK so now you can divide up the screen using those columns and any numbers from 1 to 12 where 12 is a whole screen width so the columns will be stacked on top of each other and using 6 is a half screen so the columns will take up half the page each.

```
col-1
col-2
col-3
col-4

Etc
```

After this you're just about viewport size. So you might want extra wide columns on small screens and thinner columns on medium and larger screens.

```
col-sm-12
col-md-6
col-lg-3
```

And your full thing then looks a bit like this...

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
       <!-- Content for column 1 -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
       <!-- Content for column 2 -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. You're right. Absolutely right. I just couldn't find it. I will edit my answer. So I think what's happening there is that usually a Row will automatically stretch all the way from left to right. I suspect  `row-cols-2` is going to limit the row to just two columns regardless of their width. So if you used col-4 that really should allow 3 columns side by side but I am going to guess if it's inside a `row-cols-2` then the third column will wrap to the next line.