# Can't display more than 6 columns using Bootstrap's row-cols

Tags: html, grid, bootstrap-5

I am creating an auction website. I want to show the listings as cards in columns. So far I managed to display a different number of cards on different screen sizes. However, somehow I can't manage to show more than 6 cards/columns next to each other. I want to show 8 in xxl screen-size Here is my code:

```
<!-- Grid for cards -->
<div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 row-cols-xl-5 **row-cols-xxl-8** g-2 mb-2">

    <!-- Card for every listing -->
    {% for listing in all_listings %}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100 shadow-sm">
            {% if listing.image_url %}
            <img src="{{ listing.image_url }}" alt="Listing image" class="card-img-top mx-auto"></a>
            {% else %}
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/EbXw8rOdYxOGdXEFjgNP8lh-YAuUxwhOAe2jhrz3sgqvPeMac6a6tHvT35V6YMbyNvkZL4R_a2hcYBrtfUhLvhf-N2X3OB9cvH4uMw=w1064-v0"
                alt="Listing image" class="card-img-top mx-auto"></a>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                <a href="#" class="mp-link stretched-link">
                    <h6>{{ listing.title|truncatechars:50 }}</h6>
                </a>
                <h6 class="mp-darkblue">€{{ listing.starting_bid|floatformat:2 }}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">{{ listing.description|truncatechars:100}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have already tried a number of things:

- Without images in the cards, the issue remains
- Resizing images doesn't work
- Using no cards at all, so just plain text, gives the same issue
- The container that this grid of cards is nested in is wide enough (100% screenwidth with a padding of 4)

I also just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71617553/why-doesnt-row-cols-n-work-for-any-value-greater-than-6) post, but that doesn't offer me a solution as I use CDN (I think?). So it seems that Bootstrap maybe just doesn't support this? How do I overwrite that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap 5, the '**row-cols-xxl-***' class is not available by default. You can create a custom class to handle the xxl screen size.

Add the following CSS code to your custom CSS file or inside a '' tag in your HTML file:

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
.row-cols-xxl-8 > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 12.5%;
}
```

}

This custom media query will apply the rule for screens with a minimum width of 1400px (which you can adjust according to your needs). It sets the width of the columns to 12.5% (100% / 8) when the screen size is xxl or larger.

Now, update your HTML code to include the custom class **row-cols-xxl-8**:

```
<div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 row-cols-xl-5 row-cols-xxl-8 g-2 mb-2">
<!-- Card for every listing -->
{% for listing in all_listings %}
<div class="col">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm going to try that today. However, I'm not sure if it will work as row-cols-lg-8 didn't work either. Or at least, I think I tried that. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Now as of Bootstrap 5.3 you can use "row-cols-xxl-*" But Using the Bootstrap grid you wont be able to show 8 cards on a row that's not how it works the max you could show is 6 or 12.

Example you can show 1,2,3,4,6,12 cards. The grid must always be divisible by 12.

You'd need to use flex and give each card a width of 12.5% to have 8 cards on a row at desktop size.